# Adding more actions to right click on Windows "copy and paste"

Tags: windows, registry, copy-paste

I need some ideas of adding more actions to right click on Windows `copy & paste` when dealing with files.

Our users need to have a function that opens a file when they `Paste` a copied item to a new location.

I was thinking to create a HTA window with vbs or javascript functions to accomplish this, just wondering if there will be easier way to do it by modifying default Windows `Paste` action in registry,  running a batch or vbs script.

Or if there will be other ways to do so?

Comment: I am not sure if you talk about the normal context menu, but if yes, you can add a so called Shell Extension (Explorer Extension) for the `contextmenuhandler`. Those are best implemented native (as its performance critical), but I have also seen managed code (.Net).

Comment: I dont think its context menu, i got confused by those names all the time, basically it is the menu when you right click on folders or files to make copy and paste in windows explorer when you browse files.

Comment: Yes, the one which ends with "Properties" is the context menu. There are multiple locations in registry (depending on filetype location and user) to add them.

Comment: So I can add more actions like running a script in registry? Do you know which particular reg key is for `paste` ?

Comment: I am not sure if you can overwrite paste that easily (I think actually one does that by overwriting the media type handler in the clipboard), anyway here are the context menu stuff explained: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: well this may work for me, I dont actually have to overwrite `paste`. I can create a similar one with more actions. Thanks alot.